# Best terminology for "inverse" preferences

Tags: microeconomics, preferences, decision-theory, definition

This might be related to : [Symmetric and asymmetric preferences](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/5485/symmetric-and-asymmetric-preferences).

In your experience, what is the best terminology to denote a pair of preference relations $(R,R')$ over some set of alternatives $A$ such that, for all $a,b \in A$, $a~R~b$ implies $b~R'~a$?

Comment: In math, $R'$ is usually referred to as the inverse relation of $R$. In economics, I have never seen such a definition, but I would say that "inverse" preferences make perfect sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Oliv's comment lead me to the following wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_relation
which indicates that the term "inverse" is used to define the kind of relation between $R$ and $R'$ that I described in the question.

The wikipedia article recommends to use $R^{-1}$ to denote the inverse relation of $R$.